# How to mount only a specified directory in a Box by using WebDav

Tags: chef-infra, webdav, box

I could mount a my `Box` account by using `davfs2` and with a chef recipe like:

```
mount "/mnt/box" do
  device "https://dav.box.com/dav"
  fstype "davfs"
  options "rw"
end
```

With this code all files and directories in my Box account are mounted.
I wonder is there a way to mount only a specified folder in my Box account?

Comment: I may be wrong (not using davfs) but can't it be in the uri ? (i.e: `device "https://dav.box.com/dav/<folder>"`)

Comment: Oh, it was so simple! I could do it. If you write reply as a answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting as answer for question list sanity :) )

I may be wrong (not using davfs) but can't it be in the uri ?

```
mount "/mnt/box" do
  device "https://dav.box.com/dav/<folder>"
  fstype "davfs"
  options "rw"
end
```